# VB messagebox yes/no I want the 'no' to close message box, but its closing the form i want open

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

```
Private Sub btnMain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMain.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Did you save customer info?", "Save Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
        'Me.Visible = False
        Me.Close()
        frmDuneTours.Visible = True
    ElseIf (result = DialogResult.No) Then
        frmDuneTours.Visible = False
        Me.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that the `DialogResult` property of `btnMain` is set to `None`.

Comment: You need to be aware that the `Me` keyword _in **all** the above code_ refers to the Form, not the MessageBox. With that in mind, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50181042/edit) your question, and explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I know that me refers to the form. When i hit no the current form closes. Which is why I have me.visible = true. The frmDuneTours I have set to false because that's the form that is visible when I hit no. I want the current form to stay visible. A no response means that they did not complete all fields on that form and need to go back and fix them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place Me.Close before 
frmDuneTours.Visible = True
the second line never executes because when you close the current form the application ends.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Did you save customer info?", "Save Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        If (result = DialogResult.Yes) Then
            frmSortedList.Visible = True
            Me.Close()
        ElseIf (result = DialogResult.No) Then
            frmSortedList.Visible = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that but the form I want to stay open still closes. I have one form that opens a second form, this form is the one I want to stay open. the first form is the one that is still open and I can't see the second form ( the one i want)

Comment: Check project properties by right clicking on the project name in Solution Explorer. At the bottom or the context menu is properties. Make sure Shutdown mode is set to "When last form closes.

Comment: I switched it to "When last form closes" but I still having the same problem. I can't seem to get the sub form to stay visible. Even when i do data validation on the sub form it closes after i say ok on the messagebox warning.